# Android Studio, how to create a custom adaptive mipmap ic_launcher icon for API-26

Tags: android, icons, appicon

I'm trying to update an existing app, it's been a few years since the last update and I've updated Android Studio to the most recent version v3.5.3. Among other things I want to change the app icon, so I've updated all the PNG files.

However, in the emulator it keeps showing the old default icon.

If I understand correctly, there is a new feature since API-26 which allows for something called adaptive app icons, but I can't figure out how to update this icon.

The @mipmap/ic_launcher.xml file seems to be some sort of vector file, which describes paths and strokeWidth and lines to construct the default icon. I tried and searched all over, but I have no clue how customize this type of icon to something with my business logo.

[image: Android Studio 3.5.3 app icon ic_launcher]

Do I have to turn my custom logo into a vector image? If so, how can I do this? Using which app or utility? Can't I still just use my PNG files like previously?

Comment: A very easy and brief information can be found here about Adaptive Icons, I myself followed this: https://proandroiddev.com/android-adaptive-icons-are-easier-than-you-think-3c66be2dd4dd

Comment: Did your specify android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" in your
 AndroidManifest.xml ? also can you show your ic_launcher.xml code?

Comment: Yes `android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"` is in the manifest, and the ic_launcher.xml code is visible in the screenshot above.